# Who created the Borg concept?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, borg

Who created the Borg concept?

Looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg#Concept) it is clear TNG had already started without the Borg as such, but with the idea that a new powerful adversary was needed.

This article suggests a collective effort in realising the Borg by the writers, but in reality it is usually one or two people who are initially responsible for a concept.

Is there a named person (or persons) responsible for the Borg, such as Gene Roddenberry and Leonard Nimoy were for the Vulcans initially or Branon Braga for Species 8472?

Comment: "Were the Borg inspired by Lord Dread?" I would not call it a duplicate as that question did not ask what I'm asking nor is it clear from a search that it would however the answer to that question answers this question!